# Can't write to the video memory from a function with c++ (OS dev)

Tags: c++, operating-system, kernel

I want to make a simple function that prints a char to the screen:

```
unsigned char *_videoMEM = (unsigned char*)0xb8000;
int c_pos = 0;

void printf(char c){
    //var 1
    _videoMEM[c_pos++] = (char)c;
    _videoMEM[c_pos++] = 0x0f;
    //var 2
    *((char*)0xb8000 + c_pos++) = c;
    *((char*)0xb8000 + c_pos++) = 0x0f;
    //none of the above work
}
```

the function executes (i increment a variable and print it in main()) but it didn't wrote to video memory, when i try to do the same thing but in the main() function it works and idk why or how:

FULL CODE:

```
  unsigned char *_videoMEM = (unsigned char*)0xb8000;
  int c_pos = 0;
  char z = '0';
  void printf(char c){
      _videoMEM[c_pos++] = (char)c;
      _videoMEM[c_pos++] = 0x0f;
  }
  //z+5
  extern "C" void start(){
      printf(z++);
      printf(z++);
      printf(z++);    
      _videoMEM[c_pos++] = z++;
      _videoMEM[c_pos++] = 0x0f;
 }
```

It should print to the screen `0123` but it prints    `3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

soooo i found the problem, i accidentally misplaced `0x1010010` (int the GDT descriptor) and that needed to be binary BUT, i found another problem, somehow, `unsigned char *_videoMEM = (unsigned char*)0xb8000;` dose not init the pointer so the solve whoud be like this:

```
char *BASE = 0;
int pos = 0;

void print(int color, const char *str){
    while(*str != '\0'){
        BASE[pos++] = *str;
        str++;
        BASE[pos++] = color;
    }
    return;
}

//z+5
extern "C" void start(){
    BASE = (char*)0xb8000;
    print(0x0F, "Hello World!\0");
    return;
}
```